# "Blocked loading mixed display content" for WAZE and OpenStreetMap

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have mixed content in my website. 
Recently I noticed my open street map and some of Waze API (like geocoding) ceased to function. I noticed it was due to the message:

**Blocked loading mixed display content "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/zz/yyyyy/xxxx.png"**

These links don't work through https .

Of course, I realize that the content in street map is not through https, and that my website is based on SSL. Therefore this problem arises, the problem shows in FF 23,24 google chrome 30.0.1599.69 and IE 10.
It prevents my site from viewing the map, and also WAZE API's.
It kind of stops my site from functioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox has introduced Mixed Content Blocker feature quite recently. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=860581 http://thenextweb.com/apps/2013/08/06/firefox-23-arrives-with-a-new-logo-mixed-content-blocker-network-monitor-and-more/

Comment: Is there any HTTPS support for OpenStreetMap and Waze API to use when your website is accessed in HTTPS mode?

Comment: I am looking at http://gunnicom.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/redirect-from-https-to-http-works-for-tiles-from-openlayers/ on Piotr Pelczar's response. I am not sure I understand. Why would this solution work?:  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} z=([0-9]*)&x=([0-9]*)&y=([0-9]*)&r=mapnik
RewriteRule tiles.php http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%1/%2/%3.png? [NC,L,R=301]

Comment: Would this make my server redirect the clients to http://tile.openstreetmap.org tiles ? If so, then how would it not be a mixed content just still?

Comment: I don't think the solution will work...if it works out of sudden, something must be wrong somewhere...

Comment: I solved the thing for now by proxying the tiles. It's a performance hit but restores functionality for the time being.